# How to detect Office install by Click To Run or MSI using C#

Tags: c#, windows-installer, office365, office-addins

How to detect Office install by Click To Run or MSI in C#

I'm developing VSTO add-in and get Office Information but I can't research a solution for detect Office install by  Click to run or MSI

Comment: Have you tried searching StackOverflow for this?
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwindows-installer%5D+detect+office

Answer (score 1):

You need to verify whether the `VirtualOutlook` key exists in the following location in the Windows registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\XX.0\Common\InstallRoot\Virtual\VirtualOutlook
```

or

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Office\XX.0\Common\InstallRoot\Virtual\VirtualOutlook
```

where `XX.0` stands for the Office version, i.e. 15.0 and etc.

See [Determine whether Outlook is a Click-to-Run application on a computer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/pia/how-to-determine-whether-outlook-is-a-click-to-run-application-on-a-computer) for more information.

Comment: Thanks. So if exist that key...Office is Click to run,..that right?